# Compiling multiple executable files with a static pattern rule in Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, build, gnu-make, unity-test-framework

I am writing a matrix library in C for practice.  To enforce good habits I am testing using the [Unity Testing Framework](http://www.throwtheswitch.org/unity), meaning I compile multiple test files and run them.  Since I do not know how many test files I will end up with, I've been trying to write my Makefile such that any .c file in my tests/ directory will be found and used to make a corresponding executable.

Here is my project file structure:

```
├── bin
├── include
|   ├── fml.h
├── src
|   ├── fml.c
├── test-framework
|   ├── unity.c
|   ├── unity.h
|   ├── unity_internals.h
├── tests
|   ├── check_fml_at.c
|   ├── check_fml_set_at.c
|   ├── check_fml_mem_management.c
├── Makefile
├── Readme
```

And here is the Makefile I'm struggling with:

```
BIN_DIR = bin
SRC_DIR = src
TESTS_DIR = tests

FML = $(BIN_DIR)/fml.o
TEST_FRAMEWORK = $(BIN_DIR)/unity.o

CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -g
CC = gcc

TESTS = $(patsubst %.c, %, $(patsubst $(TESTS_DIR)/%,  \
$(BIN_DIR)/%, $(wildcard $(TESTS_DIR)/*.c)))

$(info $$var is [${TESTS}])

$(TESTS): $(BIN_DIR)/%: $(TESTS_DIR)/%.c $(FML) $(TEST_FRAMEWORK)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ -Iinclude -Itest-framework
    
$(FML): src/fml.c include/fml.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -Iinclude

$(TEST_FRAMEWORK): test-framework/unity.c test-framework/unity.h test-framework/unity_internals.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

memcheck:
    valgrind $(TESTS)

check:
    $(TESTS)

clean:
    rm $(TESTS) $(OBJS)
```

Each test file needs the library (fml) and the test framework (unity).

The expected behavior when running make is for check_fml_at, check_fml_set_at, and check_fml_mem_management to appear as executables in the bin/ file, along with fml.o and unity.o libraries.  I've checked and the TESTS variable correctly evaluates to check_fml_at, check_fml_set_at, and check_fml_mem_management.  But for some reason, only the first test is built, and when I run make I only see check_fml_at along with fml.o and unity.o in the bin dir.

Why is the makefile behaving this way?  And what can I do to ensure every file in TESTS is built so I can run every test?

Thank you for any help!
-- Tomas Dougan

Comment: Your nested `patsubst` is unnecessary.  This would be simpler and clearer: `TESTS = $(patsubst $(TESTS_DIR)/%.c, $(BIN_DIR)/%, $(wildcard $(TESTS_DIR)/*.c))`.

Comment: By default make only builds the first specified target.   You can add a rule `all: $(addprefix $(BIN_DIR)/,$(TESTS))` before your other rules, and it should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be anything inherently wrong with your static pattern rule.  The reason that you are getting only one test built when you run `make` without arguments is that `make` then chooses a default *target*, not a default *rule*.  If the first rule in the makefile has multiple targets then the one that appears first is the default target.

If you want the default to be to build *all* the tests, then insert a new first rule that specifies all the tests as prerequisites:

```
.PHONY: all
all: $(TESTS)
```

---

Do note, by the way, that your `memcheck` and `check` recipes aren't going to work as you appear to intend when more than one test is designated by `$(TESTS)`.  Instead of running each test, you will run just the first, with the names of the others passed as command-line arguments.  Perhaps you want something more like

```
.PHONY: memcheck check

memcheck:
        for t in $(TESTS); do valgrind $$t; done

check:
        for t in $(TESTS); do $$t; done
```

Comment: This worked!  Thank you for helping me understand, and for going out of the way to fix my check and memcheck targets!  Bless you!